# Where is the root morpheme in the Old English cristalla (crystal) and cymen (cumin)?

Tags: morphology, old-english, middle-english

Where is the root morpheme in the Old English *cristalla* (crystal) and *cymen* (cumin)? It seems to be wrong to identify the morphemes in loanwords from etymological point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an Old English word *cristal*,

> Crystal: From Old English cristal (“clear ice/mineral”),

so I would assume that "cristalla" has the root of "cristal", and "-a" is a suffix.

For *cumin*:

> From Old English cymen, from Latin cuminum,

The Latin *cuminum* is a second declension of "cumin", so the root in this case is the word itself, as it doesn't have any affix attached.

Comment: Thank you. The arguments mentioned sound very persuasive.